# How to call redux-saga action continuously after every 60 seconds

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm working on a situation where I need to call single API continuously after every 60 seconds

My concern is how should I call the same API request using redux-saga

I'm using the normal redux-saga action, for example, get the list of employee, which fetches the list of employee every 60 seconds

Using redux-saga, react-redux and react

Answer (score 8):

```
import { delay } from 'redux-saga';
import { call, put, takeLatest, all } from 'redux-saga/effects';


export function* fetchContinuously(action) {
  yield call(api);

  yield call(delay, 60000);

  yield put({ type: "FETCH_CONTINUOUSLY" })
}

function* actionWatcher() {
  yield takeLatest('FETCH_CONTINUOUSLY', fetchContinuously)
}


export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    actionWatcher(),
  ]);
}
```

Comment: its good but I want that API to be implemented somewhere, so confused that where I need to put that API code, and from where can I call this saga function

Comment: You can put it in a specific file. The api code is not dependent on redux-saga code and it can be as simple as a fetch call. And you don't call the redux-saga function directly. You set it up so that redux actions will trigger it.

Comment: just let me know that how can I use my API in above given example

Comment: The please paste your api code so I can know what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

With new version of Redux delay have got some changes.

Example:

```
import { delay, put, takeLatest, all } from 'redux-saga/effects';


export function* fetchContinuously(action) {
  yield call(api);

  yield delay(60000);

  yield put({ type: "FETCH_CONTINUOUSLY" })
}

function* actionWatcher() {
  yield takeLatest('FETCH_CONTINUOUSLY', fetchContinuously)
}


export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    actionWatcher(),
  ]);
}
```